# Computing $P(3)$

Tags: polynomials

Assume that $P(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is a quadratic polynomial whose leading coefficient is $1$. Further assume that one of the roots of this polynomial is $P(0)$, and the remainder of the division of $P$ by $x-5$ is $12$. How could we compute $P(3)$?

$$P(x) = (x-P(0))(x-\alpha)$$

$$\begin{align}P(5) = 12 &\implies P(5) = (5-P(0))(5-\alpha) = 12 \\ &\implies -5\alpha + \alpha P(0) - 5P(0) + 13 = 0 \\ &\implies \alpha  = \frac{5P(0)-13}{P(0)-5} \\ &\implies 1 = \frac{5P(0)-13}{P(0)-5} \\ &\implies P(0) = 2\end{align}$$

From which we conclude that $P(x) = (x-2)(x-1)$ and $P(3) = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The first move I would make is suppose that $P(x) = x^2 + ax + b$. Notice that $P(0) = b$. By Vieta's formula, the other root must be $1$. Thus, again by Vieta's, $a = -b - 1$. Now we know that $P(x) = x^2 -(b+1)x +b$.

For the $x-5 $ part, we can now use long division and get an equation for b. I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)=x^2+ax+b$. Then $P(0)=b$, $P(5)=25+5a+b=12$, and $P(P(0))=P(b)=b^2+ab+b=b(a+b+1)=0$. Thus get the coefficients $a,b$ by solving either the system,
\begin{align*}
5a+b&=-13\\
b&=0
\end{align*}
or the system,
\begin{align*}
5a+b&=-13\\
a+b&=-1
\end{align*}

Comment: Wouldn't my way work as well?

Comment: @Melz you are missing the case when $P(0)=0$, in which case you will not have $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Oh, yes, apologies for that.